# How do I properly handle exceptions in constructors?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clean initialized resources if exception thrown from constructor in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723492/how-to-clean-initialized-resources-if-exception-thrown-from-constructor-in-c)

How do I handle exception in constructors if I am creating 6 objects and those objects create 5 object and fails while creating the 6th one?

Thanks.

Comment: How about link, that Als gives you here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723492/how-to-clean-initialized-resources-if-exception-thrown-from-constructor-in-c ? Are this members member objects?

Comment: What handling do you need? Normally, you would simply let the exception propagate, so that the first 5 objects get destroyed cleanly. Some more context would be helpful

Comment: RAII.(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Answer (score 3):

The usual behavior is just to let the exception propagate.  Destructors
for any completely constructed base classes and members will be called;
if the first five objects are members, they will be correctly 
destructed.

The only case where a problem might occur is if the objects you are
talking about have been dynamically allocated (using `new`).  If that is
the case: the first thing to ask yourself is why?  Why are you
dynamically allocating, and not making the object a concrete member?  In
my experience, such a need is very, very rare, except in a few special
cases (e.g. the compilation firewall idiom), in which case, there will
normally be exactly one object in the class (e.g. a pointer to the
implementation object).  In such cases, there is no problem, because if
the `new` of that object fails, nothing else has been done which needs
undoing.

*If* you find yourself in the exceptionally rare case where you really
do have to use dynamic allocation *and* have more than one such object
(e.g. because you have two subobjects which are polymorphic), then
you'll have to ensure that each of the allocations is wrapped in some
sort of a sub-object (a smart pointer will do the trick); once the first
sub-object has been successfully constructed, its destructor will be
called if the constructor fails at some later point.

Answer (score 1):

When an exception is thrown in the constructor all fully constructed subobjects are destroyed. Since it is good practice to have destructors of constructed objects look after their resoyrces, nothing needs to be done for these subobjects. What remains is cleaning up in the body of the constructor currently executing when the exception is thrown. However, this is no different to the clean-up in any other function.

Note that the destruction order is the reverse of the construction. That is, clean-up in the body starts first when all subobjects are not, yet, destroyed. Then the members are destroyed, then non-virtual base classes, and finally virtual base classes.

Answer (score 1):

At the "core" of dealing with exceptions is that virtually everything should be cleaned up via destructors. For example, if you "new" an object you get a "raw" pointer; if an exception is thrown somewhere you must make sure that this raw pointer is properly "delete"d -- but make sure you don't delete a raw pointer that hasn't been initialized.

On the other hand, if you store that pointer into an std::unique_ptr you don't have to do anything; when the unique_ptr is destroyed the object is deleted, and object-destruction happens automatically: when the unique_ptr goes out of scope, the compiler invokes the cleanup, completely invisible (so no more code-cluttering with tons of cleanup calls) and automatically (so no more 'ouch, when it takes that rare path that nobody really tested it forgets to cleanup').

The same can be applied to just about every resource; there are "auto pointers" for COM-objects (as used in DirectX, for example), most frameworks should give you a "scoped lock"-type object to wrap around mutexes (so it locks the mutex when the object is created, and unlocks it when it's destructed), and you can write tiny wrappers to deal with various Windows-handles.

Basically, if you put all your cleanup into destructors, you'll never have to "try...catch...rethrow" just to clean up. And destructors of "larger" objects will often be very simple, as virtually all the "contained" objects are cleaned up automatically by their destructors.